# Perl script to find the negative values in an excel sheet and edit the value to 0

Tags: perl

I have sample excel sheet as attached .
My script should search for the negative value in the "Rate" column and make the value to zero.

So i first started writing the script reading the values in the columns and printing the values  but my script always gives the values in zero.

Kindly help me in finding the solution or pointers where i can find relevant information.

Thanks in advance,

[Sampleexcel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JKLs.jpg)

Please find my script below

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;

my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('Emm Fill Single Radd.xls');
die $parser->error(), ".\n" if ( !defined $workbook );
for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {
my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
for my $row( $row_min .. $row_max ){
    for my $col(3){
            my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
            next unless $cell;
            print "value = ",$cell->value(), "\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have a loop that iterates only once – `for my $col (3)`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser instead of Spreadsheet::ParseExcel, and instead of $parser->parse, you need $parser->Parse

http://search.cpan.org/~dougw/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.65/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel/SaveParser.pm

Here is a working version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;
use Scalar::Util qw( looks_like_number );

my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser->new();
my $workbook = $parser->Parse('30514571.xls');
die $parser->error(), ".\n" if ( !defined $workbook );
for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {
    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();
    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
#        for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {
         for my $col ( 3 ) { # 'Rate' Column
            my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
            next unless $cell;
            my $value = $cell->value();
            next unless looks_like_number($value); # Skip headers / empty
            print "[ $row, $col ] value = ",$value, "\n";
            if ($value < 0) {
                $worksheet->AddCell( $row, $col, 0 );
            }
        }
    }
}
$workbook->SaveAs('30514571.new.xls');
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, this script also edits all the values to zero but I want only the cells with negative values to become zero. Please help me out.

Comment: It only changes negative numbers to 0.  Empty fields [ next unless $cell; ] and Strings [ next unless looks_like_number($value); ] are left alone.